# Are population principal components scale invariant?

Tags: pca, multivariate-analysis, dimensionality-reduction

**Are population principal components scale invariant?**

The answer is no.

I'm not sure whether my understanding regarding the first two is correct; please, correct me if I'm wrong. Also, I don't understand the third proof at all.

1. *Graphical intuition.* PCA results are sensitive to the shape of the data cloud (the ellipsoid).
   This is easy to visualize as the lengths of the major and minor axis change if we change the data cloud, changing the variances of the first two principal components.
2. *Theoretical proof.* Consider$$X_{p\times1}=(X_1,X_2,...X_p)\overset{\text{scale transformation}}{\longrightarrow}\tilde{X}=(c_1X_1,c_2X_2,...c_pX_p)=D_{p\times p}X$$
   $$\downarrow_\text{principal component transformation}\downarrow$$
   $$Y=\Gamma'(X-\mu)\overset{\text{are these the same?}}{\longleftrightarrow}\tilde{Y}=\tilde{\Gamma}'(\tilde{X}-\tilde{\mu})$$
   Transformation: $X\longrightarrow DX$
   Covariance matrix: $\Sigma\longrightarrow D\Sigma D'$
   Spectral decomposition: $\Sigma=\Gamma\Lambda\Gamma'\longrightarrow\tilde{\Sigma}=(D\Gamma)\Lambda(D\Gamma)'$
   Principal components matrix: $Y=\Gamma'(X-\mu)\longrightarrow\tilde{Y}=\Gamma'D'(DX-D\mu)=\Gamma'(D'D)(X-\mu)$
   So, $Y=\tilde{Y}$ iff $D'D=I_p$ i.e. if the scale transformation is orthogonal.

The following proof is an excerpt taken from  *Multivariate Analysis* by Mardia, Kent, Bibby.

3. *Proof by contradiction.*
   For $p=2$, consider $\Sigma=\pmatrix{\sigma_1^2&\rho\sigma_1\sigma_2\\\rho\sigma_1\sigma_2&\sigma_2^2}$ with $\rho>0$. Then, the largest eigenvalue of $\Sigma$ is $\lambda_1=\frac{\sigma_1^2+\sigma_2^2}{2}+\frac{1}{2}\Delta$ where, $\Delta=\sqrt{(\sigma_1^2-\sigma_2^2)^2+4\sigma_1^2\sigma_2^2\rho^2}$ with eigenvector proportional to $(a_1,a_2)=(\sigma_1^2-\sigma_2^2+\Delta,2\rho\sigma_1\sigma_2)$.
   When $ \sigma_1/\sigma_2= 1,$ the ratio $a_2/a_1$ is unity. If $\sigma_1=\sigma_2$ and the first variable is multiplied by a factor $k$, then for scale-invariance we would like the new ratio $a_2/a_1$, to be $k$. However, changing $\sigma_1$ to $k\sigma_1$ shows that this is not the case.

Comment: Hello, zaira. Let me understand the structure of the question: you provided three "proofs" of the stated claim from some sources. The third one is the one you couldn't understand, is that so? You can quote whatever portion you excerpted from. And then explicitly state what your query is.

Comment: @User1865345 The first two are proofs from my understanding of the problem although, I'm not sure they're correct. The third one is from the book (I don't understand why with scale invariance, scaling variables implies $a_1/a_2 =k$, I wrote down exactly what was mentioned there. By quote down do you mean a snippet? I can do that

Comment: That's clearer now.

Comment: Your "theoretical proof" seems to be legit. In any case, that PCs aren't scale-invariant is evident from the very transformed covariance matrix. And they are also invariant under orthogonal transformation, as you seem to conclude yourself. Coming to the excerpt, could you tell what you didn't get at all about the argument?

Comment: A quick look at the excerpt suggests that the authors wanted to show that the effect of $k$ is not what it would have been if the effect were invariant. The new ratio of $a_2/a_1$ would have been otherwise involving the factor of $k$ which is not the case. This is not a proof, but a nice illustration. The general proof that you sketched is better.

Comment: @User1865345 They've written that if it were scale invariant, we'd expect $a_2/a_1$ to be $k$ but, isn't that wrong? If it were scale invariant we'd expect the ratio of components of the eigenvector of the largest eigenvalue to be the same as it was before the transformation i.e., 1. (The new ratio is not 1 either hence, disproving the assumption but why is it expected to be the factor, k and not 1?) Where am I going wrong in this illustration?

Comment: Okay. The authors argue that $\sigma_1/\sigma_2=1\to a_2/a_1=1.$ So, if the scheme were to be scale-invariant, then $\sigma_1/\sigma_2=k\to a_2/a_1 =? $ Would it be $1$ or $k$?

Comment: @User1865345 Oh, that makes sense. Now I get it, I was misinterpreting scale invariance. In a scale-invariant scenario, when we change the scale of one variable by a factor $k$, the expectation is that the corresponding components of the eigenvector should also be scaled by the same factor $k$.

Comment: That's correct, zaira. If you have any problem, you can ping me Or edit your post.

Comment: Your "scale transformation" differs from the conventional meaning, which would concern a *common* change of scale.  Note, too, that the PCs (as directions) can be left unchanged under your generalized rescaling when they are already aligned with the axes.

Comment: @whuber I'm not sure what you mean. Do you mind expanding in an answer/ example, if possible?

Comment: See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scaling_(geometry) for terminology.  That Wikipedia article effectively answers your questions by pointing out that non-uniform scaling changes shapes, which is the geometric way of saying the PCs are altered.

Comment: @whuber So, uniform scaling is when $c_1=c_2=...$ (terminology in proof 2) versus inequality of even one of these? By "under your generalized rescaling when they are already aligned with the axes", do you mean to say that the PCs are invariant if $D=cI$ for some $c$? I don't think this is true unless $c=\pm1$, in which case there doesn't seem to be a need to address uniform scaling as a separate case? $D=$diag$(c_1,c_2,...c_p)$ with no constraints on $c_i$s is non-uniform scaling and it helps prove invariance anyway?

Comment: It depends on what exactly you mean by "PC," which is why I specified "as directions" earlier.